# Insert AD username into combobox

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to insert all my AD users-names into a powershell combobox without "@()".

I can query the AD as i expect it - only the usernames that i want are listed. 
But as i add them to a combobox a "@()" encircled them.

```bsh
function Get-TemplateUser(){

    $adusernames = Get-ADUser -Filter {enabled -eq $true} | ? {$_.GivenName -notlike ""} | select Name

    foreach($user in $adusernames){
        $ComboBoxTemplate.Items.Add($user)
    }
}
```

I expect it like this:

"User A"
"User B"

but what i get is:

@("User A")
@("User B")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can do this.

```
# This way, good if you only have to extract 1 property, bad if you need multiple.
... | select -ExpandProperty Name

# This is another way, good if your original object has more than 1 property
$ComboBoxTemplate.Items.Add($user.Name)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works!
 I would have queried every attribute.